# Image not loading from Glide library

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-volley, android-glide

The Image is not loading from the API call.
Used Volley library and Json Object request.
Used Glide library for loading images.
API : https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme

JSON Object :

```
    {
"postLink": "https://redd.it/rotkp8",
"subreddit": "memes",
"title": "It's only 7AM mom.. let me sleep!",
"url": "https://i.redd.it/5bd4d2tmuu781.jpg",
"nsfw": false,
"spoiler": false,
"author": "DragonChasm",
"ups": 298,
"preview": [
"https://preview.redd.it/5bd4d2tmuu781.jpg?width=108&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=d8ef60aaca5d8fe4b3150bcb837103391100845d",
"https://preview.redd.it/5bd4d2tmuu781.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=157e9b22042e70e6be24f82d92eca80069ccfea6",
"https://preview.redd.it/5bd4d2tmuu781.jpg?width=320&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=3e64a5592823edf82aa4b2c2081babc3f39597f0"
]
}
```

// Code of Main Activity.

```
    package com.nandini.android.memeshareapp
    
    import android.content.Context
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import android.widget.Toast
    import com.android.volley.Request
    import com.android.volley.Response
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        lateinit var memeImageView: ImageView
    
    
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            loadMeme()
    
        }

        private fun loadMeme() {
    
            val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this as Context)
            val url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"
            memeImageView= findViewById(R.id.memeImageView)
            Glide.with(this).load(url).into(memeImageView)
            val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, Response.Listener { response ->
                    val url = response.getString("url")
                }, Response.ErrorListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                })
            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
        }
    }




 // XML code.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/memeImageView"
            android:src="@drawable/download"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/meme"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shareButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/share"
            android:padding="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:padding="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
    
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

// manifest file.(Added the internet permission.)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.nandini.android.memeshareapp">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MemeShareApp">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

// Added the dependencies in build gradle (Module app)

```
    implementation("com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1")
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```

Comment: your image url is correct

Comment: check your URL its not correct pass this URL and Check:- https://preview.redd.it/5bd4d2tmuu781.jpg?width=216&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=157e9b22042e70e6be24f82d92eca80069ccfea6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `loadMeme`function is wrong and it should be like this.

```
private fun loadMeme() {
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this as Context)
    val url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"
    memeImageView= findViewById(R.id.memeImageView)
    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, Response.Listener { response ->
            val url = response.getString("url")
            Glide.with(this).load(url).into(memeImageView)
        }, Response.ErrorListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
}
```